# Why i can not use $aside in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

i have one question about angular js .
i try  to open dialog using $aside but i got injection error i try this code where i try to use ngAsige after installing `bower install angular-aside` , but i got Error like `Failed to instantiate module IndexHome due to:` if any mistake in my code please tell me where is it and after install `angular-aside` is any .js file which i have to include in my .html file ??

```
var Myapp = angular.module('IndexHome', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap', 'ngAside']);
Myapp.controller('home', function ($scope, $window, $http,$aside) {

var ServiceForm = $aside({
        scope: $scope,
        templateUrl: '/tpl/index/home/popup.html',
        show: false,
        placement: 'left',
        backdrop: false,
        animation: 'am-slide-left'
  });

  $scope.Bookservice=function(item)
  {
            ServiceForm.show();
  }
```

});

i also include .js and .css file after angular like 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As with any other angular module/dependency, in order to be able to use Angular Aside, make sure that you include angular-aside.js (along with *angular-aside.css*) and inject it where you want to use it:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAside']);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', function($scope, $aside) { });
```

Have a look at [Angular Aside Repo](https://github.com/dbtek/angular-aside), and [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/G7vMSv?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include both `angular-aside.js` and `angular-aside.css` (or their minified versions) to your index.html.

Comment: Still it give me Error

Comment: The angular-aside.js should be included AFTER the angular.js inclusion. Also, what is the error you get after `Failed to instantiate module IndexHome due to:`?

Comment: yes i got this Error if you can see this `Failed to instantiate module IndexHome due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:9000/js/controllers/angular.js:6:412
    at http://localhost:9000/js/controllers/angular.js:40:222
    at`

Comment: look my question where i include one image for included .js and .css file too